# The colors when doing "ls" at my ubuntu server diappeared just like that

Tags: command-line, ls

OK I know it's a super stupid question but driving me crazy!
I just had new 14.10 VPS setup and while setting up some basic initial stuff in the terminal out of sudden "ls" command stopped showing any colors.
I haven't done anything remotely to messing it up, and have no idea how and why it happened but is driving me crazy.

Feel free to make fun of me after probably pointing me to something obvious

Answer (score 2):

The colored output of `ls` is from a default alias included with Ubuntu. Try running `ls --color=auto` and see if you still get color. The default aliases are in $HOME/.bashrc. You can add more in $HOME/.bash_aliases. Did you edit those files during setup?

To run a command without aliases, prefix with a slash such as `\ls`.

Comment: I haven't touched those files but have su to root, maybe root doesn't have an alias?

ls --color=auto works but only as long as i have --color=auto attached, then when I do just ls it's again plain

Comment: @user240891 why on earth are you doing regular work as root?

Comment: cause i'm l33t, feel me?